get subsites and properties like SiteLogoUrl, SiteLogoDescription for the current user using rest api Batch method
I would like to retrieve sub sites for the current user using batch rest api call. I am using a script as the following one: [BatchUtils.ts][1].
From each subsite I would like to retrieve the following properties: SiteLogoUrl,SiteLogoDescription
const resp0 = await BatchUtils.GetBatchAll({
                rootUrl: siteUrl, batchUrls: [siteUrl+"/web1/_api/web?$select=SiteLogoUrl,SiteLogoDescription",
siteUrl+"/web2/_api/web?$select=SiteLogoUrl,SiteLogoDescription"],
...
                FormDigestValue: formDigestvalue
            });

it seems that batch does not work with different subsites. The url has to be the same. Any idea how to solve this? I don't want to loop through each subsite to retrieve their logo and description as it is too slow. I have 10+sites.
